# using \t to create a columned list

Tags: java, format

below is the code that loops through an entire array list printing out the values in it. I want to make the printed out version print out columns.

```
public void printList(){
    System.out.println("Task \tDue date");
    for (Task task : taskArrayList) {
        System.out.println(task.getTask() + " \t" + task.getDate() + " \t");
    }
}
```

how can I get my desired output?

Comment: Tabs may produce jagged columns depending on the contents.  Consider using String.format(String, Object...) to generate rows with specified column widths.

Comment: thanks ill try that

Comment: _What_ is your desired output?  What are the lengths of task / date fields when printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tabs won't work very well for this problem.  Try using String.format() like this:

```
String format = "%-50s%-50s";
System.out.println(String.format( format, "Task", "Due date" ));
for ( Task task : taskArrayList) {
  System.out.println(String.format( format, task.getTask(), task.getDate() ));
}
```